# cordova inappbrowser full screen (android)

Tags: android, cordova

please, i'm trying to run my hybrid app with full screen under cordova 6 with inappbrowser but without success ..

```
var ref = window.open(myURL, "_blank", "location=no");
```

in config.xml

```
 <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
```

and adding this to activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

please help! thank you.

Comment: finaly found the solution,by editing the inappbrowser.java thank you

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

under this line in InAppBrowser.java: (line 571 in current version)

```
dialog = new InAppBrowserDialog(cordova.getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar);
```